# Image to Bitmap conversion with MLKit returns null

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, google-mlkit, image-reader

I'm in Android and am trying to convert an object of type `Image` into `Bitmap` so to attach it to a `Canvas` object (Canvas takes bitmap). I convert to [InputImage](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/common/InputImage) and then try to get bitmap out of it. But `inputImage.getBitmapInternal()` returns null. How can I fix it? And is there any ways to optimize this code? There is many conversions involved.

```
Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        
InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, rotation);
Bitmap bitmap= inputImage.getBitmapInternal();
//.... 
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
```

Comment: What is the format of the image that comes from `ImageReader`? Is it RGB or YUV? You can find out using `image.getFormat()`.

Comment: int value: 35, which is YUV_420_888

Answer (score 1):

Images that the `ImageReader` reads can come in different formats (depending on who produces them). For example, video frames are typically encoded in the [YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color space (in Android it is usually referred to as YUV).

The `Bitmap` class on the other hand only supports RGB (currently).

This means, that your responsibility is to check the format of the image using `image.getFormat()` and convert the image if necessary.

The conversion of YUV to RGB, for example, is explained in this [article](https://blog.minhazav.dev/how-to-convert-yuv-420-sp-android.media.Image-to-Bitmap-or-jpeg/).

Comment: There is also this function in Android. Any difference? 
            `yuvToRgbConverter.yuvToRgb(image, bitmap);`

Comment: `YuvToRgbConverter` does the conversion but uses a deprecated API (Renderscript). So, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert the `Drawable` of your `Image` to a `BitMap`:

```
Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
Bitmap bitmap = convertDrawableToBitmap(image.getDrawable());

public Bitmap convertDrawableToBitmapNew(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

After that, you can draw it on a `Canvas`.

Comment: It's so weird. Again it says `buffer` is null: 
`ByteBuffer buffer = inputImage.getByteBuffer();` inputImage is ok though.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. There is also this function in Android. Any problems with that?           `yuvToRgbConverter.yuvToRgb(image, bitmap);`

Comment: The only "problem" with that function is, that it works only, if the Image has the correct format - 1 of a 100. I would recommend you to go the "drawable way", because this will work for any kind of Image and it makes your code less error prone.

Comment: I see. problem is I have to attach the canvas to a Surface. Not sure if I can do that with drawable.

Comment: Then return the Canvas instead. The Bitmap reference points to the content of the canvas. Everything in the Bitmap exists in the Canvas. This line draws the Bitmap on the Canvas: "drawable.draw(canvas);"

Comment: Please, double check your answer. The class `android.media.Image` doesn't have a method `getDrawable`. Possible, you confuse it with another class.